# Method of characteristic ODE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$u_t+u_x=u^2$

The initial condition is $u(x,0)=1$

Here's an attempt:
\begin{align*}
t^c{= \tau  + }F_1{(\xi )}\\
x^c{= \tau  + }F_2{(\xi )}
-\frac{1}{\tau +F_3(\xi )}
\end{align*}
I parametrized,

\begin{align*}
x^I{=\xi }t^I{=0}
\end{align*}
So, 
$u(x^I,t^I) = u(\xi ,0) = 1$

Where do I take it from here?

(Not entirely sure why the TeX language isn't working. I had Mathematica generate the TeX language)

Comment: To use tex. Place math between \$ and \$.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: I also had problems with large size math of Mathematica contained between $ symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you've been taught, but I'll follow the guide [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics).

You have

$$u_t + u_x = u^{2}, \ \ u = u(x,t)$$

Reparameterise your curve

$$x \to x(s), \ \ t \to t(s)$$

Hence we get

$$u = u(x(s), t(s))$$

Take the total derivative wrt to $s$ and equate with our original PDE

$$\begin{align}
\implies \frac{d}{ds} u &= \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\frac{dt}{ds} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{ds} \\
&= \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(1) + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(1) \\
&= u^{2}
\end{align}$$

Hence we have three ODEs

$$\frac{dt}{ds} = 1 \implies dt = ds \ \ (1)$$

$$\frac{dx}{ds} = 1 \implies \frac{dx}{dt} = 1 \ \ (2)$$

$$\frac{du}{ds} = u^{2} \implies \frac{du}{dt} = u^{2} \ \ (3)$$

Now, $(2)$ implies

$$x(t) = t + x_0 \ \ (4)$$

where $x_0$ is your integration constant. From $(3)$ we find

$$\begin{align}
\frac{du}{u^{2}} &= dt \\
\implies \frac{-1}{u} &= t + f(x_0) \\
&= t + f(x - t) \ \ \text{[using $(4)$]} \\
\implies u &= \frac{-1}{t + f(x - t)}
\end{align}$$

Using the condition $u(x, 0) = 1$

$$\begin{align}
1 &= \frac{-1}{f(x)} \\
\implies f(x) &= -1 \\
\implies f(x - t) &= -1 \\
\implies u(x, t) &= \frac{-1}{t + f(x - t)} \\
&= \frac{-1}{t - 1} \\
&= \frac{1}{1 - t} \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: If you need anymore help, just comment below.

Comment: Your help is invaluable. I'm very thankful.